# Transaction shows up in Etherscan although I didn't make that transaction

Tags: etherscan, scam

so yesterday I sent 350 USDC and today I saw a new transaction of 350 of another ERC-20 Token popping up in Etherscan on my address which appears to have the ticker USDC in a different writing.

I obviously didn't send it and when clicking on the sender address I get following pop-up:
[image: etherscan pop-up]

So I have two questions:

1. Although I am pretty certain that my wallet is safe. Could there be any reason to think otherwise?
2. How does the original creator of the transaction manage to make it seem like I sent those tokens?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the tx hash

Comment: @ZartajAfser this is the tx hash: 0x6286a1dfacf4e9b9431af637c4db0688231c16535286cc3e539acc0d1b18eb84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what all Etherscan checks when it lists token transfers. Most likely it's just listening to events emitted by token contracts.

Anyone can create a contract which emits arbitrary events - even an ERC20 token contract. So the contract could, for example, be otherwise regular ERC20 token contract, but it has some weird (malicious) logic about which events it emits and when. Etherscan then listens to these events and gets confused.

Your wallet is most likely not compromised.

Comment: Yes you are right. If looking at the original Tx-ID I can see that the original sender just interacted with some contract.

Anyways, that makes it easier for me to understand. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Btw, this is how it looks on Etherscan looking at my wallet address:

[image]

I am pretty sure from what I can see the "scam-TX" tries to mimic a real TX of the past to eventually make me confuse the receiver next time and send it to the address the scam TX sent to? Not sure though.